Solving the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Schrödinger equation with Dirac delta function potential
Problem
I'd like to use Mathematica to solve the groundstate energy (smallest eigenvalue) of the 1d Schrödinger equation with an attractive delta potential ($\lambda > 0$).
$$
\left\{- \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx^2} -\lambda \delta(x) \right\} \psi (x)   = E \psi(x) 
$$
My attempt
I use
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{\epsilon}{\pi(x^2 + \epsilon^2)}  = \delta( x) 
$$
with finite $\epsilon$ to approximate delta function.
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 1;
\[Lambda] = 1;
H = -1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda]  \[CurlyEpsilon]/(
    Pi (x^2 + \[CurlyEpsilon]^2));

Then I use NDEigenvalues:
NDEigenvalues[{H, DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, Abs[x] == 5]}, 
   \[Psi][x], {x, -5, 5}, 3, 
 Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}]

Questions
No matter how I adjust $\lambda$, $\epsilon$ and the grid size MaxCellMeasure, it always gives me
{0.049348, 0.197392, 0.444132}

The result becomes
{2.77408*10^-12, 0.049348, 0.197392}

when I remove the Dirichlet boundary condition.
This is definitely incorrect. Delta potential is a standard problem in quantum mechanics. Wikipedia has documented the solution, which after translating to our unit is
$$E = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$$
Can you help me what is the correct way to model delta function in NDEigenvalues? It may also be helpful to plot the eigenfunctions.
Edit 1
@user64494 pointed out a mistake: I forgot to add $\psi(x)$ to the delta potential term. Here is the new Hamiltonian
\[CurlyEpsilon] = 0.0001;
\[Lambda] = 1;
H = -1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda]  \[CurlyEpsilon]/(
    Pi (x^2 + \[CurlyEpsilon]^2)) \[Psi][x];

NDEigenvalues[{H, DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, Abs[x] == 5]}, 
   \[Psi][x], {x, -5, 5}, 3, 
 Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}}]

However the result is still not correct
{0.19738, 0.287403, -0.498863}

Edit 2

I can't believe I missed it!
I always assumed the first output is the smallest eigenvalue (like many eigensolver), but actually the third eigenvalue is approximately -0.498863, which is close to $-\frac{1}{2}$ :)
Thanks @yarchik for pointing out.
Edit 3
Reason to use DirichletCondition:
The solution of the bound state wavefunction has an exponential decay $\exp( - \kappa |x|)$. So I think the Dirichlet boundary condition will not change the smallest eigenvalue when the size of the system is large.
Nevertheless, the Dirichlet boundary condition is not necessary. One just need to go to the fourth output (which I didn't include)
Energy[\[Lambda]_] := Module[{\[CurlyEpsilon] = 0.001, H},
  H = -1/
      2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 
       2}] - \[Lambda] \[CurlyEpsilon]/(Pi (x^2 + \[CurlyEpsilon]^2)) \
\[Psi][x];
  NDEigenvalues[{H}, \[Psi][x], {x, -5, 5}, 10, 
    Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}] ]
Energy[1]

{0.0492994, 0.075588, 0.443957, -0.49249, 0.616972, 1.2334, 1.59035, \
2.41763, 2.96698, 3.99664}

It is important to remember that the outputs are not ordered, so you might want to print more eigenvalues to find it.

You omitted \[Psi][x] in \[Lambda]  \[CurlyEpsilon]/(     Pi (x^2 + \[CurlyEpsilon]^2)).

(i) What are the  correct values of those  eigenvalues? I don't find it in the linked Wiki article. (ii) As the documentation says in mild words "Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points".

Your boundary conditions correspond to a particle in a box or an infinite square well.  The width of the box/well will affect the energy levels.  At $\lambda = 0$ you should recover the particle in a box states.  For an analytical approach, see SE Physics link.
There is also a Wolfram demo that may be of interest.

@LouisB, I know how to solve it analytically. But here I want to use mathematica because the real problem I'm facing with delta potential can't be solved analytically. I have also tried to remove the DirichletCondition, then the energy is always positive.

@user64494, in wikipedia bound state section, the energy of the bound state is $-\frac{m\lambda^2}{2 \hbar^2}$. In our unites, $m = \hbar = 1$, so the eigenvalue is $- \frac{\lambda^2}{2}$.

Sorry, you asked for the first three eigenvalues by NDEigenvalues[{H, DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, Abs[x] == 5]},     \[Psi][x], {x, -5, 5}, 3,   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00001}}}].

@anecdote If I correctly understand your Wikipedia link, the righthand side of your ode should be E \[Psi][x] not E \[Psi] I think

I think it is a legitimate question, moreover it shows some preliminary work.

@user64494, there is only one bound state, whose energy is $-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$, the others are scattering states with a continuous spectrum. So I wish to see a gap. For the purpose of this problem, we can just compute the first (smallest) eigenvalue.

@UlrichNeumann, I was sloppy, it should be E [Psi][x] on the RHS.

@anecdote Thanks. Shouldn't this expression E psi[x] also be included in the definition of H?

@UlrichNeumann, well $E$ is the eigenvalue of the differential operator $-\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx^2} + \lambda \delta( x) $, like the eigenvalues of a matrix, it is to be determined by NDeigenvalues.

Also H = -1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda] *DiracDelta[x] \[Psi][x]; \[Lambda] = 1; NDEigenvalues[{H,    DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, Abs[x] == 5]}, \[Psi][x], {x, -5,    5}, 3, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> Min[e, 0.01]}}}] outputs {0.0493481, 0.197395, 0.444162}.

Exactly formulating, what is the spectra of {H, DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, RealAbs[x] == 5]} or/and {-1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda] *DiracDelta[x] \[Psi][x], DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, RealAbs[x] == 5]}.

@user64494, I don't know how mathematica implements DiracDelta. If it is the true DiractDelta, then the finite element numerical procedure gives you reasonable results, given the meshgrid size is finite. Loosely speaking, the DiracDelta is infinitely thin; so for numerics, we have to use a tempered distribution with a finite $\epsilon$ and the set the grid size to be smaller than $\epsilon$ for the equation to "feel" the existence of this potential.

@anecdote:  Sorry,  your  above talks (for example, " the DiracDelta is infinitely thin") are not any serious arguments. That's all.

@user64494, hence it's "loosly speaking". The intuition points me to the right direction, e.g. using a smaller grid than epsilon. A mathematically rigorous statement is beyond my ability. You can read the book recommended yarchik.

Your approach is correct, but there is some misinterpretation of results. They indeed converge towards -1/2 as can be seen here:
lev[e_]:=Module[{λ=1,H,x},
          H=-1/2 D[ψ[x],{x,2}]-λ e/(Pi (x^2+e^2)) ψ[x];
          NDEigenvalues[{H, DirichletCondition[ψ[x]==0, Abs[x]==5]},
          ψ[x], {x,-5,5}, 3,
          Method->{"SpatialDiscretization"->{
           "FiniteElement",
           "MeshOptions"->{"MaxCellMeasure"->Min[e, 0.01]}}}]//Min
  ]

LogLinearPlot[lev[y], {y,10^-4,10^-1},
   MaxRecursion->0, PlotPoints->10, FrameLabel->{ϵ,Energy}, PlotTheme->{"Frame","Monochrome"}]


I was asked for clarifications about the spectrum of such operators with $\delta$-function potentials. In the book by G. Dell’Antonio Lectures on the Mathematics of Quantum Mechanics I, Section 20.7 we read: 1) "Such perturbations cannot be described by a potential; their precise description is within the theory of quadratic forms." 2) This case "can be recovered as limit in the norm resolvent sense of the Laplacian on the real line plus a regular potential $V_\epsilon(x)$ in the limit when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$". This latter point allows one to substitute a $\delta$-function potential with some smooth potential $V_\epsilon(x)$ as was proposed in OP and is used here.
Furthermore it is known:

For the 1d Schrödinger equation with an attractive $\lambda>0$ $\delta$-function potential on $\mathbb{R}$ has a discrete spectrum (single point $E=-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$) and an essential spectrum $E>0$.

For the 1d Schrödinger equation with an attractive $\lambda>0$ $\delta$-function potential on a finite interval of extension $L$ there are only discrete states. For instance, when $\lambda=0$ their energy is given by $E_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi n}{L}\right)^2$. Furthermore, $\delta$-potential is a finite-rank perturbation that per Weyl's theorem does not introduce any essential spectrum into the system.



Can you explain  what //Min does? Without it lev[0.1] performs  three eigenvalues {{{0.186414, 0.307441, -0.317063}}, {\[Placeholder]}} and lev[0.01]  results in {{{0.19626, 0.291321, -0.454524}}, {\[Placeholder]}} for me.

@user64494 Min take the minimal of the three. I don't know why the first output is not the minimal. The parameter e is $\epsilon$. The delta function is exact, when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. So smaller delta gives your more accurate result. However, with smaller delta, the resolution of grid should also be higher. We both set the resolution to be epsilon.

Can you explain what  is the aim of //Min ?  Without  the explanation all that is built on the sand. Not being a physist, I don't understand the OP's " there is only one bound state..."

Also H = -1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda] *DiracDelta[x] \[Psi][x]; \[Lambda] = 1; NDEigenvalues[{H,    DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, Abs[x] == 5]}, \[Psi][x], {x, -5,    5}, 3, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> Min[e, 0.01]}}}] outputs {0.0493481, 0.197395, 0.444162}

Therefore, we face with the weaknesses of NDEigenvalues.

The answer would be grounded with a solid reference concerning  "...there is only one bound state, whose energy is −λ/2, the others are scattering states with a continuous spectrum. So I wish to see a gap."

@user64494 Yes, I will try to add a nice reference or expand my anwser.

Exactly formulating, what is the spectra of [{H, DirichletCondition[ψ[x]==0, RealAbs[x]==5]} or/and [{-1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda] *DiracDelta[x] \[Psi][x], DirichletCondition[ψ[x]==0, RealAbs[x]==5]}?

@yarchik: Thank you for the addition to the answer. Unfortunately, I don't see an answer to " what is the spectra of [{H, DirichletCondition[ψ[x]==0, RealAbs[x]==5]} or/and {[{-1/2 D[\[Psi][x], {x, 2}] - \[Lambda] *DiracDelta[x] \[Psi][x], DirichletCondition[ψ[x]==0, RealAbs[x]==5]}? " and " ..there is only one bound state, whose energy is −λ^2/2, the others are scattering states with a continuous spectrum. So I wish to see a gap" there.

@yarchik: In particular,  your claim "As I said, there are no scattering states for the finite interval, only bound states. If I am not mistaken your code describes exactly this case. When the interval grows to infinity, the spectrum becomes continuous for $E>0$, but one state with negative energy $−λ^22/2$ remains"  is still  ungrounded as well as  the claim"but the spectrum is discrete". I prefer references and arguments  over ungrounded claims. That's all.

There is nothing to solve.
The $\delta$ potential at $x=0$ says, that the solution is an exponential and that the first derivative has a unit step, so $\psi$ has unit kink like
$$\psi(x) =e^{- \lambda  \left|x\right|}$$ which is a bound state with negative energy
$$-\frac{1}{2} \psi''(x) =  \frac{1}{2} \ \frac{d}{\text{dx}} \ ( \lambda \ \text{sign}(x) \ \ \psi(x)) = -  \frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \ \psi(x) + \lambda \ \delta(x) \ \psi(x)  $$
A simple method is to solve the finit negative wall problem with continous $\mathcal L^2 $ solution over the wall.
  Assuming[\[Epsilon] > 0 && En < 0, 
  FullSimplify @  ComplexExpand @
    DSolve [{\[Psi]L''[x] == -En  \[Psi]L[x] , 
   \[Psi]R''[x] == - En \[Psi]R[x], 
   -1/2 \[Psi]''[x] - 1/\[Epsilon] \[Psi][x] - En == 0}, 
  {\[Psi][x], \[Psi]L[ x], \[Psi]R[x]}, x] ]

$$ \begin{align}\psi L(x) & \to c_1 \ e ^{ \sqrt {-\text{En}}\ x}\ +   c_2 \  e ^{- \sqrt {-\text{En}}\ x}
\\ \psi R(x) &\to c_3 \ e ^{ \sqrt {-\text{En}}\ x}\ +   c_4 \  e ^{- \sqrt {-\text{En}}\ x}
\\ \psi (x) & \to -\text{En} \ \epsilon \ + \ c_5 \ \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)\ + \ c_6 \ \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)\end{align}$$
Adjust the constants for continuity and $ \psi L,\psi R \in \mathcal L^2$ at $x=\pm \epsilon$ and let $\epsilon\to 0$

What is $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)$?

The function must be even and the exponentials must be descending, so $c_1,c_4,c_6 =0,$. Of course all limits $\psi(0),\psi  L(0), \psi R(0)$ can be set to 1.

In this case what is $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\right)$?

Sorry, but the analysis of the spectrum of bound states in the square well is lengthy and not very illuminating. There is a finite number of bound states, odd and even sine, cosine interiors with external decaying exponential tails. The fit at the walls uses $\psi(\pm L), \psi'(\pm L)$ continuity for a second order equation to fix the eigenvalues. In the limit square well  $ \to \delta $ potential the negative eigenvalues elevate to positive ones, only the even bound ground state survives, with limit $e^{-|x|}$ with the kink mimicking an infinite small half cos period.
